How Do I Override Button Commands in TKinter Simpledialog?
I am using tkinter simpledialog.askinteger in Python and it is working beautifully, but I would like to change the command associated with the "Cancel" button. I have looked at the Python documentation on this command, found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html
However, all it says is that you can override the button commands; it does not provide instruction on how one would go about doing that. I am rather new to Python, so I am afraid I need it spelled out a little more explicitly.
The relevant code, when simplified, looks something like this:
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox

prioritychoice = True

while prioritychoice == True:
    
    P1Cont = simpledialog.askinteger('Priority Level','Which priority level would you like to view?')
    
    # the code then displays a dataframe containing the correct priority info
    
    prioritychoice = messagebox.askyesno('Continue', 'Would you like to see information for a different priority level?')

[This code produces a dialog box that looks like this] (https://i.sstatic.net/TMjsw63J.png)
I would really like to override the command for the 'Cancel' button so that it breaks out of the while loop instead of just closing the window.
Is this possible? I see a lot of answers on Stack talking about buttons in a custom tkinter popup, but not specifically within the simpledialog.

I'd advise against using a while loop in a GUI application, as more often than not you can hang your UI while the loop is running. Can you [edit] your question to include a [mre] (something we can run)? That will help us better understand what you're looking for.

I would also like to point out that the GUI event loop will wait until the dialog window is closed, so it should be enough to do something like if simpledialog.askinteger('Priority Level', 'Which priority level would you like to view?'): ... else: ...

The edited version should now include code that can be run. Thank you.

You don't need to override the Cancel command. Simply check whether P1Cont is None, if yes then break the while loop.
prioritychoice = True

while prioritychoice == True:
    P1Cont = simpledialog.askinteger(
                 'Priority Level',
                 'Which priority level would you like to view?'
             )
    if P1Cont is None:
        # Cancel button clicked, break the while loop
        break

    # the code then displays a dataframe containing the correct priority info
    prioritychoice = messagebox.askyesno(
                         'Continue', 
                         'Would you like to see information for a different priority level?'
                     )

